Passing custom parameter to viewinvoice.tpl
I just want to display custom error messages,
To achieve this, I  want to pass a parameter as error codes,
The gateway/callback file ends with this function;
callback3DSecureRedirect($invoiceIdWhmcs, $paymentSuccess);

But it seems it doesn't take third parameter.
Then I tried to redirect it as a custom url but it seems sessions are not working with this method.
header("Location: "https://xxxx.com/viewinvoice.phpid=11470&paymentfailed=true&abc="bca"

So, is there a way to pass a variable to the viewinvoice.tpl?
Thanks!
